# How do I create relationships from substrings in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a set of 'tag' nodes and 'category' nodes, and wanted to generate relationships between the two by testing if the category's name is a substring of the tag's name.
This was my approach thus far (apologies, I'm one day into cypher so this may be fundamentally flawed but I am yet to find something equivalent to reverse engineer thus far)

```
match(cat:category)
match(tag:tag) where tag.name =~ '.*'+cat.name+'.*'
merge (tag)-[:belongs_to]-(cat)
```

Error:

```
Type mismatch: expected Boolean, Collection<Boolean> or Collection<Collection<Boolean>> but was String (line 2, column 48 (offset: 67))
"match(tag:tag) where tag.name =~ '.*'+cat.name+'.*'"
```

The error seems to revolve around the use of =~ and concatenated strings, any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the order in which the expression in the WHERE clause is 
evaluated. You can get around it by being explicit: enclose the string concatenation in parentheses.

```
WHERE tag.name =~ ('.*' + cat.name + '.*')
```

I tried quickly looking for documentation on cypher operator precedence but it wasn't in the [operator chapter](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/query-operators.html), so I'm not sure where this is documented.

Comment: forgot to thank you for this, just what I needed to fix it :)

Comment: Glad to hear, if you come across documentation of operator precedence in cypher feel free to edit and add it to the answer–it would improve understanding to know what the rules really are.